# PHP MYSQL multiple or single DISTINCT/UNIQUEvalues

Tags: php, mysql, unique, distinct

Currently I have this query:

```
SELECT column1,column2 FROM table
```

column1 needs to be distinct, column2 does not.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, NON-DISTINCT column2 FROM table
```

Now I know that doesn't make sense but I need column1 to be distinct and column2 to be anything. How would I do that.

Comment: Do you want a single bla1 at random whenever you have two or more PIDs?

Comment: well i don't want to do "select * from table" because i only want to get back "pid" and "bla1" - where 'pid' is distinct and 'bla1' isn't. the outcome being rows 1-3

Answer (score 2):

```
select pid, group_concat(distinct bla1) as bla1s
from table
group by pid;
```

The above will get you 1 row for each pid and you'll be able to see if there are extra bla1s without introducing a new column or having to settle for a random choice of multiple bla1s.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (fastest):

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
GROUP BY pid
HAVING min( id )
```

second (slower) option:

```
select *
from `table` t1
where
    t1.id = (select min(id) from `table` t2 where t1.pid = t2.pid)
```

Comment: :( isn't there a way to do it without the "group/min"?

Comment: Why don't you want the grouping? SELECT DISTINCT is for getting unique values only, other values you try and select will be ambiguous. Should it select 2 or 7 as the bla1?

Comment: There is no way how to do that without group, or there is - subselect, but this will be slow. Or you can delete these records if you don't want them. Why you don't want to use group by?

Comment: goat -> i want to do this (select pid,bla1 from table) but i only want pid to be distinct // malek -> because i think there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: without group by, but not easier :-) I think you will not find easier way:
select *
from test t1
where
  t1.id = (select min(id) from test t2 where t1.pid = t2.pid)

Comment: well if i do "select distinct pid,bla1 from table" does distinct apply to pid, bla1 or both?

Comment: Actually, since he's using MySQL and if the value of bla1 doesn't really matter he could simply use `SELECT pid, bla1 FROM table GROUP BY pid`. Note that this SQL isn't portable, and will only work on MySQL (most - if not all - other RDBMSs will complain about the use of GROUP BY without aggregate functions).